# How to write excel file with chart using js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, js-xlsx, sheetjs

Using `SheetJS js-xlsx` `"xlsx": "0.15.1"` js is there a way to write excel file with chart.

Basically I want to export html page that contains chart into an excel file.

HTML page is getting exported successfully but the chart in the page is not getting  displayed.

Here is the code I have used

```
let wb =XLSX.utils.book_new();

 let element: any = document.getElementById('page1');
 let ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);
 XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,ws,'page1');
```

Comment: what charting library are you using to draw chart in html ?

Comment: Provide a sample of `element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Community build or the Pro?

As stated [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/925#issuecomment-403310387), *The Community build reflects the data cached in charts as worksheets. Other chart-related features, including writing and reading metadata, are included in the Pro compendium*.

Remember to include your work as `Chartsheet`, just in case. It will continue to render it as a `Worksheet` if you are using the community version, but it will help us to understand the desired behavior that you are seeking.

If you provide more reference for the code, maybe we can show you some shortcuts to make it work.